# How to find if english words exist in string

Tags: python, parsing, dataframe, web

I am trying to parse some web domains (tens of thousands) to see if they contain any English words.

It is easy for me to parse the domains to grab the main part of the domain with `tldextract` and then I tried to use `enchant` to see if they exist in the English dictionary.

The problem is I do not know how to split the domains in to multiple words to check, i.e. `latimes` returns as False but `times` would return as True.

Does anyone know a clever way to do look if there is an english word contained at all in the strings?

Thanks!

Comment: this is surely not the best way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve ...  and in manycases it may always be ambiguous

Comment: any suggestions? i am trying to separate a list of english and spanish domains into two lists.

Comment: whynot lookthem up with whois ?

Comment: is there a way to do it programmatically? looks like there is some paid API's

Comment: add free to your search most of them are free up to a limit ... oh you exceed the limit ... you might have to pay 5.00 or something (or do 11k a month until you get through the list) you can also use some fuzzy string matching to try and guess ... but latimes will probably think its spanish in all cases except whois

Comment: thanks, i will try to make this work :)

Comment: this looks good but it will take a while https://freedomainapi.com/free-whois-api.html (1 free query per minute ... there are 43k minutes in a month :/ ) (and to be fair just because its registered as us doesnt necessarily guarantee that it is, although it its not registered us then it almost certainly is not)

Comment: its a bit time sensitive so maybe ill just suck it up and pay...else tmux session? lol

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do that in a hurry, you could just chip off letters from the beginning *or* the end of the string, and check if it's a known word; if it is, cut it off and repeat. With e.g. 50k words 20 letters each, at worst you'll do 1M lookups. With a lookup taking e.g. 5ms (hitting an HDD every time), it will take 5000 seconds (about 1.5 hours), shorter than you'd spend coming up with a better algorithm.